# Conditional bean injection throws error " No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available"

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, conditional-statements, javabeans

I have defined a conditional bean :

```
@Conditional(CustomClass.class)
public class CustomClass implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return false;
    }

    @Bean(name = "bean1")
    public DataSource dummy() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

In another class, I am injecting bean1 as follows:

```
public anotherClass(@Qualifier("bean1") DataSource dataSource) {
}
```

But, when the conditional class match method returns, false, 
i get:

> "No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available"

If match returns true, there is no error.

Isn't the purpose of conditional beans to load beans conditionally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the purpose of conditional bean loading.

You get an error when the `matches` method returns false because there is no longer a bean available for autowiring. You should define a `DataSource` for that case as well (so a bean of type `DataSource` is available event if your current `matches` returns false).

You could do that in another `@Configuration` that extends `Condition` and for which the `matches` method would return the opposite value of your currently defined `matches`.

Comment: i defined one more, but it stil complains no qualifying beans, probably because it tried to loads the first one , but since the conditional returns false, it does not,